# infinite history in bash, when using multiple terminals(terminator) without losing commands and messed up order

Tags: bash, command-history

I want infinite history, because I type a lot of commands I can forget at the spot and would like to have it stored somewhere as a reference. But by just setting `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` it does not work good because IIRC the commands are stored only when terminal window is closed, and tends to overwrite each other. So my current setting is this:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  # no duplicate entries
export HISTSIZE=100000                   # big big history
export HISTFILESIZE=100000               # big big history
shopt -s histappend                      # append to history, don't overwrite it
```

however this has one drawback. When using multi-pane "terminal app" like terminator, the history order for each pane is incorrect, as IIUC, then I won't lose any command, but history is central, thus separate terminals cannot say what was *their* last command.

I need not to stick to bash history management, I have no issue with anything else which would solve this, ie: no lost commands, each terminal is capable to find any command while still being able to scroll back in time in order this specific terminal invoked the commands. If you have experience with McFly or anything else which would work, please advise. However I'd rather not like to steer away from bash, because it's more commonly used, and I need to be able to share scripts with majority or people.

Motivation: imagine one terminator app, splitted into several virtual terminals while doing testing. I want to invoke some commands it "its" specific pane for clarity. It would be speedup for me, if I could be able just hit up-enter to rerun previous command, which I cannot, because actions from other panes changes the order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Separate terminals cannot say what was their last command

A hacky solution is to mess around with the history file **name** (`HISTFILE`):

> By default, history is stored in `~/.bash_history` file. Add the
>   following line to the `.bash_profile` and relogin to the bash shell,
>   to store the history command in `.commandline_warrior` file instead of
>   `.bash_history` file. I’m yet to figure out a practical use for this.
>   **I can see this getting used when you want to track commands executed from different terminals using different history file name**.
>
> ```
> # vi ~/.bash_profile
> HISTFILE=/root/.commandline_warrior
> ```

Source [Hack 56. Change the history file name using HISTFILE](https://linux.101hacks.com/command-line-history/histfile/)

I will leave it up to you to figure out the precise mechanics, but this should be enough to get you started.

It would be nice, for example, to use the terminal window title or something similar to set the history file name but I don't know enough bash to figure out how to do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have this on .bashrc

`PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "$(history 1)" >> ~/history4ever'`

It is from this book
[about shell scripting](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=ANo3sSiNx1EC&pg=PA273&lpg=PA273&ots=IowrATEWPA&focus=viewport&dq=history4ever%20bash&hl=pt-BR) (in pt_BR).

Comment: seems ok.So with this,I could remove `export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups` which does not work reliably anyways, remove also `shopt -s histappend` to remove interference between shells. Then each shell will only overwrite bash_history when existing and will keep it's own order.File `.bash_history` would be incomplete and potentially messy, but `history4ever` would be ordered and complete. And I would have 2 commands: session history and global history.

Comment: Could you also advice, how to do efficient filtering,not do log `cd` etc? Sure I can pipe&grep it, but if I don't want to spawn too many greps and use some "daemon"?

Comment: I don't know how to filter directly on bash, maybe you can filter inside the `$(history 1)` sub-shell, before it sent to history4ever.